# How to derive the Gamow factor in a simple way?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, quantum-tunneling

I want to know how to derive the Gamow factor (how to solve the integral and which approximation I have to do)  without the centrifugal correction.
$$V(r) = V_N(r)+V_c(r). $$

The [Gamow factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamow_factor) is given by

$$G=\int_R^{r_c} \sqrt{2m(V(r)-E)} dr . $$

Comment: a few more details? what integral?

Comment: Closely related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156919/